# Создание столбцов в БД используя Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Наткнулся на одну проблемку:
КАк мне создавать программно столбцы, в таблице, в БД, если в настройках hibernate мне надо маппить таблицу заранее?
А я не знаю сколько столбцов в таблице, так как она динамически изменяется. Мне надо удалять столбцы и добавлять и т.д. Да и маппить на POJO объект я то же не представляю как. Кто сталкивался, как вы решали это?

Comment: Таблица не должна динамически изменять во время работы приложения

Comment: Для создания структуры БД лучше использовать системы миграции, такие как Flaway, Liquibase и др., а не средства Hibernate

Comment: Но ведь в cassandra столбцы изменяются динамически. В этом ее принцип. И может хранить до 2 млрд. столбцов. Или я ошибаюсь? Мне надо что то похожее, только не cassandra.